# Likelihood of pathogenicity

Tags: sampling, binomial-distribution, likelihood, genetics

Suppose that the probability that a mutation in a bacterium is pathogenic is 1/100. Now, a new allele is found in a population with a frequency of 5%.

What is the probability that this mutation is pathogenic?

Now suppose that you take a sample of 100 bacteria. In this sample, 20% of the bacteria with this allele are pathogenic, and the other 80% is not pathogenic. What is now the likelihood that the new allele is pathogenic?

I have hunches to each of those questions, but I don't have much backbone to them. My answers I gave were 1/100 and 1/76. The first I got through reading the question and the second through a likelihood comparison through bayes rule. I
am in no way sure of my answer.

Comment: Is this a test question or a homework question?  If not, and if you still need an answer, you might draw one by rephrasing the question without technical jargon.

Comment: @rolando2 It was a test question. It was determined to be "awkwardly worded" by the professor after grading and he gave anyone who showed any scratchwork full credit. So... this has no answer.